# warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]

Tags: c, pointers, integer, warnings

Here's my program (the vars are german)

```
    int ABFRAGE(int max,int min){
    int eingabe;
        do {
            printf("\t>");
            scanf("%i",&eingabe);
        } while (eingabe > max || eingabe < min);
        return eingabe;
    }

    #define ABFRAGEERGEBNIS Abfrageergebnis = (int)ABFRAGE
int main(void);
   int Abfrageergebnis;
        ABFRAGEERGEBNIS; <-!
        if (Abfrageergebnis == 2)
        NAMENSAENDERUNG(i,Name);
        if (Abfrageergebnis == 1)
    getchar();
        STRING_PROLOG;
```

It should get a number save it and do that ,what the if parts are saying. But at the <-! are the warnings

Comment: A pointer and an `int` are only compatible in a very few cases, on a modern 64-bit system almost never. If you want to use a type that can hold either a pointer or an integer, use `intptr_t`. But I don't recommend it (reason being obfuscation and readability).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg jm, its not working . do i have to add some special libaries? i just changed int with intptr_t was that even right?

Comment: is there another way to define this without using int?

Comment: `Abfrageergebnis=ABFRAGE(2,1);`

Answer (score 0):

I think, with your current code, you're reading a memory address into an int, which isn't what you're trying to do. I'd recommend making your second line of code `int *eingabe;`.

EDIT: I was completely wrong. I think the error is here: `#define ABFRAGEERGEBNIS Abfrageergebnis = (int)ABFRAGE`. You're calling the function ABFRAGE but not specifying the arguments max and min. You also don't need (int) there.

The function ABFRAGE is fine the way it is- you just need to change the line I mentioned to `#define ABFRAGEERGEBNIS Abfrageergebnis = ABFRAGE(max, min)`. You also need to define max and min, which I did in main while I was testing this.

Answer (score 0):

That macro is horrible, why are you using it?

This:

```
#define ABFRAGEERGEBNIS Abfrageergebnis = (int)ABFRAGE

ABFRAGEERGEBNIS; <-!
```

will expand into

```
Abfrageergebnis = (int) ABFRAGE;
```

In other words, you are assigning *the address of the `ABFRAGE` function* to the `int` variable `Abfrageergebnis`.

Kill the macro, and just do:

```
Abfrageergebnis = ABFRAGE();
```

to do a proper *call* of the function.